# SQL Query Help (Joining two tables)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables in my database with the following schemas:

```
ratings table:
usedId
movieId
rating

info table
movieId
imdbId
```

The movieId values in each table are the same (i.e movieId 1 is the same movie in both).

Each movieId & userId appears multiple times in the ratings table.

What I am trying to do is create a new table that looks like:

```
new table:
userID
movieId
imdbId
rating
```

Where the imdbId is added for each row that matches the movieId of its original table.

Comment: Very basic question. Look for `Join` in Sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select ratings.userID, ratings.movieId, info.imdbId, ratings.rating from
ratings inner join info on ratings.movieId = info.movieId
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can manual join the two tables:

```
SELECT r.userID, r.movieId, i.imdbId, r.rating 
FROM ratings r, info i 
WHERE r.movieId = i.movieId
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `SQL Join` to create your expected table.

```
select Rating.userID, Rating.movieId, Info.imdbId, Rating.rating 
from ratings as Rating
inner join 
info as Info on ratings.movieId = info.movieId
```

To get more details of join check this [inner join link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: Yes, I think so. Query is still running after 15 minutes (21m rows in table) so we will see on completion.